# string method not returning value from table in database

Tags: c#, mysql, methods

i have been struggling with the following method for a while and have not really found anything of use.

I have a bunch of dynamically created text boxes, the text box names correlate with the primary key in my database, so when that text box comes up (a button moves on to the appropriate text box during normal operating conditions) it uses the `textbox.name` as in input for a string method in the hopes that that method will return the corresponding value from the database and assign it to the text box.

now, i am not getting any errors but it always either returns an empty string or, if i declare the string with whatever variable, then it displays that variable in the text box which tells me that displaying data in the text boxes are working fine and my problem lies somewhere within my method.

```
    public string DisplayValues(string BID)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (MySqlConnection myCon = new MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = root"))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table_raw WHERE id = '@value';", myCon))
            {
                try
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", BID);
                    using (MySqlDataReader myRead = myCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (myRead.Read())
                        {
                            result = myRead.GetString("_VAL").ToString(); //looks for column _VAL where id = the methods input value.
                        }
                        myRead.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

again, i am NOT getting any errors i am just not getting any data into my text box.

implementation:
`textbox.text = DisplayValues(tbID); //tbID is declared elsewhere`

so what is happening is that text box is showing blank.

when i change `string result = string.Empty;` to `string result = "1"` then the text box displays `1`

That is what i have and what is happening, what i want (if it wasn't obvious) is to make the `textbox.text`display the data in `_VAL` column in my database where the primary key is equivalent to `textbox.name`

Other things to note, `_VAL`is a `varchar()` datatype, `tbID`is a string and in the database it is stored as a `varchar()` and i was going crazy with `.ToString` out of pure frustration. (eliminate doubt), the database is fine as i am writing data to it, just need to read that data to those boxes now.

there are quite a number of text boxes on my form (each with a generated name, which is also the primary key in my database), that is why i am trying to implement this method in this manner.

I would like to do it this way (i am a somewhat intermediate level programmer), but if there is a "better" way, i will entertain that option after i have this one working.

I do hope i have included everything.

much love.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM table_raw WHERE id = '@value';
```

use

```
SELECT * FROM table_raw WHERE id = @value;
```

Otherwise you are searching the string `'@value'` and not the passed parameter.

Side-note: [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Comment: funny enough, i was using the column name, and i usually do, but changed it to * because i wasn't getting my result. but thank you...this works, i thought it may have been something simple. -hugs and tugs

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT * FROM table_raw WHERE id = @value;`, I would suggest to use column names instead of `*`, because it affects performance and you cannot use Alias in this case.
Better you write Stored Procedure not the query in your code.

Comment: thanks, and yea, most of my stuff is self taught, but i am busy doing some mysql courses specifically for stored procedures and triggers.